# Using Insertion Sort When Writing to a File in Java

Tags: java, insertion-sort

I'm trying to use insertion sort when writing to a file. I am fairly new to Java and can't seem to find a solution. Here is the code I am working with:

```
private void add(DbObject d) throws IOException {
    database = new RandomAccessFile(fName,"rw");
    database.seek(database.length());
    d.writeToFile(database);
    database.close();
}
```

What this is doing is adding person information into a file. One of the fields is a SSN#. Currently, if I was to add an SSN# of 222222222 and before it was already a record with a SSN# of 444444444, the 222222222 record would go after the 444444444 record. I need to do it to where the 222222222 will insert itself before the 444444444 record.

I know I have to compare the two, and somehow store one in a `tmp` variable of some sorts, but I don't seem to know where to start from. Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Comment: In the vast majority of file systems (independent of programming language) you cannot "insert" data in the middle of a file.  Either you must overwrite existing bytes with exactly the same number of new bytes, or you must read the file and rewrite it as a new, longer file with the data inserted.

Comment: (I think what you want to do is impractical.  Either do an "in core" or "offline" sort of your data or use something resembling a database, such that the actual order of the data is unimportant.)

Answer (score 3):

1. You'll need to read the file in order to determine where the new record needs to go.
2. You'll need to make room for the new record
3. You'll need to write the new record in the proper location.

1 & 3 are pretty easy; 2 is the nasty bit.  2 main approaches:

1. Copy the part of the file that comes after the new record far enough down in the file to make room for the new record.
2. Make a copy of the file by copying the stuff that comes before the new record, then writing the new record, then copying the stuff that comes after.  Then you can delete the old copy of the file and rename the new one.

All of this is somewhat easier if each line in the file is the same length.

BTW: This really isn't an insertion-sort.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm going to sound useless and annoying, but I have no clue how to get this to work. I'm trying to get it to go through file pointers, but don't exactly know how to tell it to rewrite the file...

Comment: Use seek to get to the position in the file you want to start reading/writing from, just as you used it in your example to move to the end of the file.